# Find an integral matrix with all maximal minors = 1 or -1?

Tags: linear-algebra

*The problem:* Let $m \leq n$ be arbitrary.  Does there exist a $m \times n$ matrix $\textbf{A}$ over $\mathbb{Z}$ with the property that all maximal minors are equal to 1 or -1 (i.e. all $m \times m$ submatrices of $\textbf{A}$ are unimodular)?

Another way of phrasing the problem that might look better is: does there exist a collection of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{Z}^{m}$ such that every subset of size $m$ spans (i.e., is a basis for) $\mathbb{Z}^{m}$?

(I'm particularly interested when $n = m^{2}$).

Some classes of matrices that I've looked at are **totally unimodular** matrices - these are matrices with EVERY *non-singular* submatrix unimodular. This is a little different obviously - and totally unimodular matrices seem to be generated from incidence matrices of graphs, so that they might not be a good place to draw examples from.

This property seems to be called called the "Haar property", at least when replacing $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mathbb{C}$ and the answer is positive in this case. (http://arxiv.org/pdf/1408.2022.pdf for a reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying by the inverse of the first $m$ columns of $A$, we can assume those first $m$ columns form the $m \times m$ identity matrix $I$.  All the entries in all the other columns must be $\pm 1$ (i.e. $A_{ij} \ne \pm 1$, replace the $i$'th column of $I$ by the $j$'th column of $A$, and the determinant will be $A_{ij}$).

Now consider two columns $u$ and $v$ of all $\pm 1$.  Consider the matrix obtained from $I$ by replacing column $i$ with $u$ and column $j$ with $v$.
In order for this to have determinant $\pm 1$ (in fact in order for it to be nonsingular), the $2 \times 2$ submatrix
$$ \pmatrix{ u_i & v_i\cr u_j & v_j\cr}$$ must have determinant $\pm 1$.  But this is impossible: the determinant of such a matrix is even ($0$ or $\pm 2$).

We conclude that the largest possible $n$ is $m+1$.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you - the answer is tight too: take the identity matrix with the last column all 1's.